# How to retrieve Teams filesFolder Items with Graph api/HTTPS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using this endpoint to reach Teams files folder:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/filesFolder](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/filesFolder)
That is fine to see the top-level items, but if I want to reach a level down, i.e. retrieve a particular file, or when I have a 2nd-level folder and want to reach the 2nd-level folder content, by:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/filesFolder/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/filesFolder/content), it throws error:
{
"error": {
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": "Unable to find target address",
"innerError": {
"date": "2023-06-27T17:31:09",
"request-id": "391ed357-91c5-469d-b6af-91d984de011e",
"client-request-id": "dfd55cc2-2495-fb4f-3d73-b3878ca9c33e"
}
}
}

I also tried to reach the content from the filesFolder "parentReference -> driveId" with this endpoint:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{drive-id}/root/children/{item-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root/children/%7Bitem-id%7D)
but got errors as well:
{
"error": {
"code": "itemNotFound",
"message": "The resource could not be found.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2023-06-27T17:33:50",
"request-id": "eb142392-aa9f-4e15-a911-46ca6519d7b8",
"client-request-id": "f8c7c3ca-c34d-6631-5751-c6ea6bd36db9"
}
}
}

I am new in developing with Graph Api, there are issues others posted a year or two ago that I now ran into but without any new answer/solutions. Is Graph api mature enough for developing application with?

I am expecting to get to the filesFolder items and retrieve item metadata.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve files in the root of the drive, use the root relationship on the drive, then access the children relationship.
Use the Below Graph API-

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children
```

also please check if you are putting the correct {drive-id} and {item-id}.

You will get the drive-id using below Graph API-

```
GET /me/drive
```

Reference Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-id

Answer (score 0):

A bit esoteric, but after some trial n' error, I found this to get to the subfolder items (especially for the revision history on an document):

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{channel-name}/{folder-name/path}/{document-item-name}:/versions](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root:/%7Bchannel-name%7D/%7Bfolder-name/path%7D/%7Bdocument-item-name%7D:/versions)

Comment: ok, but knowing the TeamsID or the ChannelId I cannot seem to find the driveID for the files tab for that channel - how to?